# How to change the quick setup after opening blender for the second time?

Tags: selection-tools

Changing the selection in the quick setup menu after opening blender the second time

Comment: The first startup menu shows only on the first startup of a new Blender version. It's possible to make it think it's your first time again by deleting some preferences files, but that's quite overkill. Plus most of what the first startup menu shows is also modifiable in Blender's preferences anyways. So what do you need to so exactly?

Comment: as mentioned you can get quick setup menu back by removing `userpref.blend` but you would reset all your settings

Answer (score 1):

You can find the options provided in the quick setup menu in *Edit > Preferences*

Language settings are under the *Interface* tab, keyboard shortcuts under *Keymap*, and the theme settings under *Theme*.

[image]